# not able to install jabber with emacs

Tags: arch-linux, emacs

i downloaded emacs-jabber from git and it created a directory called emacs-jabber and it had files like jabber.el , configure.ac etc. installation guide told me to use

`./configure and make and make install`

to install jabber.el but when i did

`./configure`

i did this in emacs-jabber folder that was created

it shows no such file or directory
and please tell how to integrate facebook with emacs-jabber
Thanks

Comment: Copy-paste the exact commands you ran (so that we know from what directories you ran them and so on). And copy-paste the error messages you got. (“no such file or directory”, yeah, ok, but which file? We don't know because you didn't copy-paste.)

Comment: i had updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use automake and autoconf. The [README](https://github.com/legoscia/emacs-jabber/blob/master/README) mentions that, but slightly below the part on ./configure, make, etc:

> ### Special notes for GIT version
>
> [...]
>
> To generate the configure script, make sure that autoconf and automake
>   are installed and run "autoreconf -i".